# Dygraph file path on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, dygraphs

If i place the .csv file in the same folder as dygraph-combined.js - /var/www - then the graph is drawn, see below:

```
g = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
        "meterLogPercentageThreshold.csv", // path to .csv file
        {
            rollPeriod: 1,
            showRoller: true,
            fillGraph: false,
            ylabel: 'Power (W/h)',
            xlabel: 'Date and Time',
            showRangeSelector: true,
            colors: ['#00aa00']
        }
      );
```

But if i specify a other location, then the graph is not drawn, can someone please point me in the right direction?

??? This does not work and it is the same file, i know i am doing something silly, just not sure what?

```
g = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
        "/media/Power/meterLogPercentageThreshold.csv", // path to .csv file
        {
            rollPeriod: 1,
            showRoller: true,
            fillGraph: false,
            ylabel: 'Power (W/h)',
            xlabel: 'Date and Time',
            showRangeSelector: true,
            colors: ['#00aa00']
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in a URL, dygraphs will issue an XMLHttpRequest for it and attempt to parse the returned data as CSV.

It's important to realize that you're working with url's, not directories. This url is an address to a file on the server. You have to make sure the URL is accessible and returns data in text format.

2 possible solutions:

- Place the file in `/var/www` and specify the relative path of the file in this folder.
- Place a url to server scripting files like .asp and .php which perform actions on the server before sending the response back. In these scripting files you can then fetch your file from your local file system and return the data in text format.